# delete selected item in listbox using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA code to delete a selected item on my listbox and delete theme at the same time from the worksheet.
I have the Following code :

```
Private Sub Sup_IT_Click()
If mode_edition = True Then

    If UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.ListIndex = -1 Or UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.ListCount < 1 Then
    MsgBox ("Please select an item")
    Else
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete ?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        Num_IT = UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.List(UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.ListIndex, 3)

            Dim Plage As Range
            Set Plage = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Personne).Range("B23:DD23")
            Set Trouve = Plage.Cells.Find(what:=Num_IT)
        If Trouve Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("error: IT  not found!")
        Else
        Sheets(Personne).Activate
                Range(Cells(Trouve.Row, Trouve.Column), Cells(Trouve.Row + 2, Trouve.Column)).Select
                Selection.Delete (xlShiftToLeft)


            Actu_IT
        End If
    Else
    End If
End If
    Else
MsgBox ("Vous n'avez pas les droits requis")
End If
End Sub
```

Where Actu_IT is a code to update my listbox after deleting :

```
Private Sub Actu_IT()
Personne = UF_Profil_Edit1.TextBox_Nom & " " & UF_Profil_Edit1.TextBox_Prenom.Value

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Personne)
Fin_Col_IT = ws.Cells(23, 256).End(xlToLeft).Column
UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.ColumnCount = 4
UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.ColumnWidths = "50;450;60;20"

Set Plage = ws.Rows(23)
Set Plage2 = ws_Liste_IT.Columns(2)
For i = 2 To Fin_Col_IT
Val_Cherch = ws.Cells(23, i).Value
Set Trouve = Plage.Cells.Find(what:=Val(Val_Cherch))
If Trouve Is Nothing Then
Else

Set Trouve2 = Plage2.Cells.Find(what:=Val(Val_Cherch))
If Trouve2 Is Nothing Then
Else

UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.AddItem Trouve2.Offset(, 2)
'---------------Nom de l'IT------------------------------
UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.List(UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.ListCount - 1, 1) = Trouve2.Offset(, 1)
 '---------------Date de fin de la formation------------------------------
UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.List(UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.ListCount - 1, 2) = ws.Cells(24, Trouve.Column)
 '---------------n? PE---------------------
 UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.List(UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.ListCount - 1, 3) = Trouve2

End If
End If
Next i
  End Sub
```

is there another way to delete items from a listbox ? 
Appreciate any help.
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean: ListBox1.RemoveItem (ListBox1.ListIndex)

Comment: To clear listbox (delete all items) [ListBox.Clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.listbox.clear) .. out of [ListBox Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.listbox#methods)

Comment: EvR   Your answer is excellent